# SQL Server - Pass Table as Parameter to function within select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

Have setup a TableType as

```
create type KeyPairTable as Table (KeyValue nvarchar(50), 
                                   [Description] nvarchar(500))
```

I have a table which can be simplified to

```
create table Elements (SharedKey int,
                       ElementName nvarchar(50), 
                       SourceSQL nvarchar(500))
```

and I have a function with header

```
create function RunElement(@SharedKey int,
                           @ValuesTable KeyPairTable readonly)
```

now what I need to do is effectively:

```
select RunElement(SharedKey, 
                  case when SourceSql is not null then [X] 
                       else [Y] 
                  end) from Elements
```

where [X] is taking the SQL statement stored in SourceSQL and passing it in as a KeyPairTable and [Y] is an empty table (e.g. it won't be used / isn't needed)

I would like to avoid cursors / loops and do this in a select as this is a simplification of the problem and the select actually joins several tables.

Comment: something is fishy here, maybe it is just naming, but your KeyPairTable (which I would expect to have a key and a value) seems to only have a value and no key -- or does KeyValue actually mean Key?

Comment: KeyValue is the 'Key' and Description is the 'Value'... but 'Key' and 'Value' as reserved words in sql hence my own custom column names, btw this is a simplified example, what im asking is how to get a 'table' to pass into a function within a select

Answer (score 0):

> what im asking is how to get a 'table' to pass into a function within
>   a select

Ok, there are some parts of your example code that still does not make sense to me, but I believe this example should be what you are looking for (or close enough you will understand.)

```
DECLARE @myTable KeyPairTable 

INSERT INTO @myTable (KeyValue, [Description])
  SELECT SharedKey, 
         CASE WHEN SourceSql IS NULL THEN [X] ELSE [Y] END
  FROM Elements

SELECT RunElement(SharedKey, @myTable)
```